Any way to specify type of returned variable if that type is not exported by API in typescript?
I'm working with the OpenTelemetry SDK in typescript.
I want to have a simple class like this:
import { MeterProvider } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics"

class MyClass {
  private meter : Meter | undefined;  // <--- cannot specify this type
  
  private startup(provider : MeterProvider) {
    this.meter = provider.getMeter("my-meter");
  }
}

I also want to have some functions, external to the class, which would be defined as follows:
doStuffWithMeter(meter : Meter) {  // <--- same here
   meter.doThings() // ...
}

The problem is, as far as I can tell, the otel SDK does not export the Meter type, so I cannot use it to specify the type of the meter member/argument. Is there any way I can get my hands on this type and/or any workaround to this?

• Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] without unrelated problems (like meter property never being initialized, or meter in startup not being a variable.  Maybe change it to the code at this playground link. • Once you do that, you could use ReturnType to get a handle on the type, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

Ah yes, ReturnType is precisely what I was looking for.

Since the getMeter() method of a MeterProvider is not generic and returns the desired unexported Meter type, you can just use the ReturnType utility type to make a type alias:
type Meter = ReturnType<MeterProvider["getMeter"]>
// type Meter = Meter

(In case it's confusing: when you use IntelliSense to view it it looks like a circular definition: type Meter = Meter.  But the type named Meter on the right of the equals sign is the anonymous unexported Meter from the module, while the one on the left is the type alias you're assigning it to.)
Playground link to code
